# My python praw script throws a 404 error?

Tags: python, praw

I'm just trying to do a simple script that will give the 5 top hot posts on a subreddit and I get a 404 error?

I can't see where I'm wrong.

Here is the code

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = 'na',
                     client_secret = 'na',
                     username = 'na',
                     password = 'na',
                     user_agent ='na')

subreddit = reddit.subreddit('Python')

hot_Python = subreddit.hot(limit=5)

for submission in hot_Python:
    print(submission)
```

Comment: Are you actually putting 'na' or are those just placeholders for this post?

Comment: yeah just placeholders

Comment: Alright. And I'm assuming you already checked that all info was 100% correct? Including the secret? https://github.com/reddit-archive/reddit/wiki/OAuth2-Quick-Start-Example#first-steps

Comment: Yes all the info is correct

Comment: i just get a massive error including a http 404 response

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I went and ran this myself and I had 0 issues.

[image]

Looks like you have an issue with (most likely) your client_id or client_secret.